# Show author link using custom user model (DRF)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model via `AbstractBaseUser` -

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_user_dir_path,
                              default='user_placeholder/user_image_placeholder.png')
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

So, I have a second model `Post`, where I can see "author" filed -

```
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, I created PostsViewSet. Check my serializer -

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    isFan = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", read_only=True)
    author = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        read_only_fields = ('users',)
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_isFan(self, obj) -> bool:

        user = self.context.get('request').user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            return None
        else:
            return services.isFan(obj, user)
```

After this, when I create a post, I take an error -

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField` try to find the URL API to which the specific author can be retrieved, according to your URL schema.

You may have wrongly config your `urls.py`